# How to get the number of Packages in a project in golang

Tags: go, linter

I have meet a problem, and I need the number of pkgs in a project. I tried to use walk, but I failed. Anyone has an idea?

[image: example of how to count the number of pkgs]

Comment: "I failed" is not a problem description. What happened?

Answer (score 3):

Go has a very handy built-in subcommand, list, for just this sort of task.

Try performing:

```
go list ./...
```

This will give you a list of all the packages under the current directory.  You could trivially pair this with a utility like `wc` to get your desired answer:

```
go list ./... | wc -l
```

You can always pass a package path to inspect, but the `/...` on the end tells go to recurse.  You might want to also run `go help packages` for more info.

There are even more [sophisticated actions](https://dave.cheney.net/2014/09/14/go-list-your-swiss-army-knife) you can perform with `go list` like filtering, that you might be interested in.